# Background videos turning green on mac?

Tags: html, css, video

I have some divs with background videos on my website, but for some reason on Mac (firefox and safari) they're all appearing with a weird green tint. I'm including them as ordinary videos and not altering the colors in any way, and they work fine on all browsers on windows. Here's the HTML:

```
`<div class="container-fluid splash">
            <video autoplay loop class="video-background" muted plays-inline>
                <source src="splashpage.m4v" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>`
```

And the CSS:

```
    .splash {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And here's what it looks like on the site:

[background video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhmNU.jpg)